# c# XXXXX is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am having a problem with "xxxx is inaccessible due to its protection level". I have read a lot of manuals how to test classes with internal access. I have inserted

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("UnitTests, PublicKey=mykey")]
```

in ProjectA into a class which I want to test. And in my TestProject I have also added a reference to ProjectA. Both have the same *.snk. But it keeps throwing the error.

Some suggestions?

Comment: Want to share some code?

Comment: Are you sure, the assembly name and private key used is correct?

Comment: I have only one internal class with couple private methods, when I tried to change internal to public tests worked.

Comment: I have an snk file, so I used SN-Tp <path>

Comment: How are you calling the method that has the 'internal' specification? Directly? Using reflection? Is the test infra you are using reflecting over the methods and then calling them for you?

Comment: "couple private methods" you cannot access `private` methods, only `internal` methods.

Comment: calling it directly, when I change internal to public everything works

Comment: I have changed them to public, but no success either..

Comment: may be smth with my public key.. I have generated it using SN -Tp path to my dll. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/19/visual-studio-tip-get-public-key-token-for-a-stong-named-assembly.aspx

Comment: So `UnitTests` is the name of your unit test assembly? Is that what's specified in the `AssemblyTitleAttribute` for it?

Answer (score 9):

Without seeing your specific class, it's hard to be precise, but ensure the following:

- Your class is either `internal` or `public`
- Your method is `internal`
- The `InternalsVisibleTo` property contains the full namespace of your test project.

i.e. if your test project is `MyProject.UnitTests`, then you need to have that in your `InternalsVisibleTo`, e.g.:

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("MyProject.UnitTests")]
```

I've never used the PublicKey part of the `InternalsVisibleTo`, so I can't comment on that, but you could try removing it. Usually works without it for me.

```
[assembly: System.Runtime.CompilerServices.InternalsVisibleToAttribute("MyProject.UnitTests")]
```

**Public Key Value**

Assuming those are all fine, and it's still not working, I would guess it's something to do with the PublicKey value you are entering. At a quick web search, it appears that you don't enter the key *name*, but the key *value*. To get that, follow [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/archive/2006/04/17/using-internalsvisibleto-attribute-with-strong-named-assemblies.aspx) Set of instructions to get that value. I'll quote the instructions here for posterity.

> The InternalsVisibleTo Attribute can be used to allow another assembly (such as your Unit Test assembly) to see the internal members of your assembly.  I prefer this method to either putting unit tests in my primary assembly or to using the VSTS feature of autogenerating accessors to my private members.  (Those are real fun when you go to refactor a project…)
>
> Now most of the info you will find about this refers to the earlier beta usage.  The attribute used to take in a PublicKeyToken but now takes in a PublicKey.
>
> To use the InternalsVisibleTo Attribute:
>
> 1. Run sn.exe -p MyStrongNameKey.snk MyStrongNameKey.PublicKey
>
> This will extract to public key to a file with the .PublicKey extension.  (I hate using the .pub extension because it is seen as a Microsoft Publisher file…)
>
> 1. run sn.exe -tp MyStrongNameKey.PublicKey
>
> This will display your public key for you.  Copy this key.
>
> 1. Create an attribute as such:
>
>    [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo( "MyProject.UnitTests, PublicKey=PASTE-YOUR-PUBLIC-KEY-HERE" )]
> 2. Note that the public key that was displayed was 5 lines or so.  Remove the line breaks from the public key and paste it into your attribute.
> 3. You are done!  The assembly MyProject.UnitTests can now see the internal members of your assembly.

Comment: my class is inernal, methods are also internal, but I tried to change methods to public - no result. The assembly seems ok, according to your example.

Comment: I've updated with some data I found RE the public Key.